# Heat treatment processes in Nickel-Based Superalloys?

Tags: metallurgy, material-science, alloys

What is the difference in heat treatment process between Wrought
Ni-Based superalloys &cast Ni-Based
superalloys

Comment: If you provide the detail of the heat treatments then we will see.

Comment: By "cast" do you mean single crystal or orientated grains ?  By "forged" do you mean mechanically combined materials ?

Comment: Only polycrystal sir